# lost video call when mobile screen got locked (Agora)?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, agora.io

I am using the agora video SDK in the flutter app. The problem is **when user locked their phone for few seconds/minutes while video consultation and again unlock phone, they found they lost video connection of another side. ** I am trying to find out the problem but have not found it. Please help me.

I am trying to find out the problem but have not found it. But I show this is not happening in android version 12 but less then 12 it is happening

Answer (score 0):

The app does not continue when you are running in the background. You could probably use a plugin like [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) to run the task in the background. You can find more information about background processes in general [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes).